# What is the best way to replicate/copy a big mysql database

Tags: mysql, database-replication

We want to run BI analytics on a (copy of a) mysql database.

Currently we get a full mysql dump file daily, but it takes up to 16 hours to import this file into our "BI" server. The dump file itself is about 9GB big, resulting in 360 tables with a total of 20GB (on disk); the biggest table file (.ibd) is around 6GB.

I am no mysql expert, but I think that the import takes so much time since the dump file only imports data, and the database needs to re-index everything from scratch...( as a side question: Any thoughts maybe on how to improve the import?) We have been looking at having a separate SSD for the datafiles, added some more RAM/CPU to the server, but that does not really improve the import speed...

Is there a way to have some sort of "snapshot" of the source database, so that it can be copied over as-is instead of importing?
I think about a .zip file with all the .ibd files (and other necessary files)

Comment: There is a whole site dedicated to this sort of problem: [dba.se]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, importing a large mysqldump is notoriously slow. The dump file contains the definitions of indexes, but not the index storage itself. So the indexes must be rebuilt every time you import the dump file.

At my company we use [Percona XtraBackup](https://www.percona.com/software/mysql-database/percona-xtrabackup).

It's a *physical backup* tool, meaning the result is not an SQL dump file that must be imported. It just makes a copy of the .ibd files and the iblog files to reconcile transactions. The .ibd files contain both rows of data and indexes.

We use this backup & restore solution to clone databases up to 100x as large as yours.

Percona XtraBackup is free and open-source.

There are a few caveats:

- Doesn't work on Windows last I checked (I haven't checked in several years, because I don't use Windows).
- You can backup without interrupting service on the source instance, but to "restore" you need to shut down your local MySQL Server, copy the backup into the datadir, and restart the MySQL Server.
- It's nearly impossible to import just one database to an instance. In other words, backup and restore is for the full instance, with all tables and schemas. This will overwrite anything else you have on your local instance. Whereas mysqldump is more flexible because you can dump & import just one table or just one schema, and you can import to a running MySQL Server instance without stopping it.

It's worth mentioning that if you don't use a proper backup tool, you should not try to make a zip archive of the MySQL data directory of a running MySQL Server. You're almost certain to get a non-consistent copy of the data files, meaning they will be corrupt and not restorable.